# Automate download of file dynamically generated by http request

Tags: database, perl, vbscript, download

I am trying to automate the download of a bunch of csv files that are generated from a database based on which checkboxes are selected on a form. The website generates the csv file with the click of a 'Download' button. I found the URL to the download prompt using Firebug (and determined how it changes based on checkbox selection), but am unsure how to use it since it is dynamically generated and does not contain a file path. An example URL is the following:

https://www.quantcast.com/download/plannerCSV?&d0Id=10&sc=1&mr=10000

What is the best way to go about doing this? I looked into the Python mechanize module and briefly glazed over pydermonkey, but had trouble finding documentation on downloading dynamically generated files. I also found some suggestions on [other forums](http://www.techrepublic.com/forum/questions/73-176694) for using VBscript and Perl-- I prefer to use Python if possible since I am most familiar with it, but if another language is more appropriate, I will learn what I need in order to accomplish this task--I just hope to do it efficiently! Comments from anyone with experience/knowledge/insight on this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: If you were using Perl I would say use Mechanize, therefore I imagine Python's (copycat) Mechanize should work too. You might want to stick with it, even if the docs are lacking. Try something easier first, like a static webpage.

Comment: [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) documentation, [mech-dump](http://p3rl.org/mech-dump) form dumper

Comment: (turned out I was just missing the login information in order to access the download URL)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way for you to do this is to use the command line tool wget. If running a UNIX/Linux it's already there. If you're running Windows then a Win32 version can can be downloaded from: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

The you can use a shell/batch script that will download the file for you.

Example for Windows:

```
set id=10
set sc=1
set mr=10000

set my_url=https://www.quantcast.com/download/plannerCSV?&d0Id=%id%&sc=%sc%&mr=%mr%
set filename=planner.csv

wget %my_url% --output-document=%filename%

:
: do stuff with file
:
```

Comment: When I ran that, I got the following:
'd0Id' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Hmm, can you explain why this happens?

Comment: OK I put the URL in quotes but then I got "Unknown/unsupported protocol"--is it because the URL is not a file path in csv format?